# Storing value of second checkbox in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, checkbox

I've tried finding an answer for this - and I expect it's going to be very easy to fix.

I have an HTML form with a list of events, each of which has a tick box (`name="registrations[]"` and an ID pulled from the database as the value). A customer can tick as many boxes as they want to indicate whether they want to attend.

Alongside each event is a second tick box (`name="lunch[]"`), which a customer can use to indicate whether they require lunch at that event.

Now, I'm able to insert multiple events into the database using:

```
foreach ($_POST['registrations'] as $registration) {
/// do database work
}
```

(with `$registration` used to store the event ID for every booking).

My question is this: how would I go about storing the value of that second checkbox in the database? Thanks, as always, for your help.

Edit - database schema, as requested:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings2` (
  `booking_id` int(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `company` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `service` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `telephone` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `cars` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `advertising` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `display` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bag` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lunch` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `masterclass` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_info` text,
  `promo_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `electric` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `booking_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`booking_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=104 ;
```

Comment: Can you show your database schema?

Comment: Is there a specific problem/reason why you cant create an additional column ie `launch` next to `registration` and store the value there?

Comment: So, is the main question what the best database schema would be for this problem, or are you asking how to tell which lunch-checkbox belongs to which registration-checkbox?

Comment: @nvcnvn I've added the schema to the original question for you.

Comment: @Quasdunk I'm happy with the schema - just not sure how to get the yes/no value for the lunch checkbox and add it to the database, in the same row as the value for the registration checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of the lunch checkboxes to the event ID - just as you do with the registration checkboxes.

```
foreach ($_POST['registrations'] as $registration) {

    $lunch = in_array($registration, $_POST['lunch']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';

    // do the insert with $lunch variable which is now Yes or No
    // INSERT INTO bookings2 (...) VALUES (..., '$lunch', ...)
}
```

This will store your lunch variable as `Yes` or `No` - this will work but it would be more efficient to store a boolean `1 or 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can build you form like below:

```
<form name="abc" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="registrations[1]" value="1"> aa &nbsp; 
   <input type="checkbox" name="lunch[1]" value="1"> aa &nbsp; <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="registrations[2]" value="2"> BB &nbsp;
   <input type="checkbox" name="lunch[2]" value="2"> aa &nbsp;<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="registrations[3]" value="3"> CC &nbsp;
```

aa

On submit you will get values like below:

```
Array
(
    [lunch] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

    [registrations] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

    [submit] => submit
)
```

Than you can loop you php foreach like-

```
foreach ($_POST['registrations'] as $key=>$registration) {
   //you can access lunch value as
   $lunch  = isset($_POST['lunch'][$key]) ? $_POST['lunch'][$key] : 0;
}
```

Comment: $_POST[$key] shouldn't be $_POST['lunch'][$key]?